# Finding $\int_0^1\bmod(x,g)dg$, where x is any real positive number

Tags: integration

(for clarification, $\bmod(a,b)$ is the remainder of $a/b$, so $\bmod(5,2) = 1$)

Graphing $y=\int_0^1\bmod(x,g)dg$ in desmos gives a [continuous graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/toy1ljmlut) (though it takes ages), so it seems like it should be properly integratable. Wolpham alpha gives a [visual representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%280%2C1%29%20mod%285%2Cg%29dg%20), but not an answer

Comment: What means "integratable"?

Answer (score 3):

Let $m$ be a positive integer. Then

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} (m \text{ mod } g) \, \mathrm{d}g
&= \int_{0}^{1} \biggl( m - g \biggl\lfloor \frac{m}{g} \biggr\rfloor \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}g \\
&= m - \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\lfloor mt \rfloor}{t^3} \, \mathrm{d}t \tag{$t = 1/g$} \\
&= m - \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{k}{m}}^{\frac{k+1}{m}} \frac{k}{t^3} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= m - \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} k \cdot \frac{m^2}{2} \left( \frac{1}{k^2} - \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \right) \\
&= m - \frac{m^2}{2} \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \right)  \\
&= m - \frac{m^2}{2} \left( \frac{1}{m} + \zeta(2) - \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{k^2} \right)   \\
&= \frac{m}{2} - \frac{m^2}{2} \left( \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{k^2} \right) .
\end{align*}

This solution can be easily adapted, with due modification, to the case when $m > 0$ is no longer an integer. Since the answer is a bit less elegant in this case, let me leave it as an exercise.

(As a hint, note that for $x > 0$ we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} (x \text{ mod } g) \, \mathrm{d}g
&= x - \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\lfloor xt \rfloor}{t^3} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= x - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{\max\{x,k\}}{x}}^{\frac{\max\{x,k+1\}}{x}} \frac{k}{t^3} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= x - \frac{x^2}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \left( \frac{1}{\max\{x, k\}^2} - \frac{1}{\max\{x, k+1\}^2} \right).
\end{align*}

Now simplify the summand according to whether $k < x-1$, $x-1 \leq k < x$, or $k \geq x$.)